# I have one problem to select a string from a column which is not match with other column values in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have two columns in one table.

- table name: Table1
- first Column name: Address
- second column name: locality

How would I select substrings from an Address which does not match the locality column.

Column1- Address

- Third Floor, Century City Mall, Kalayaan Avenue, Poblacion, Makati
  City
- Little Tokyo, 2277 Chino Roces Avenue, Legaspi Village, Makati City

Column2- Locality

- Century City Mall, Poblacion, Makati City
- Little Tokyo, Legaspi Village, Makati City

I just need those parts of address column values which is not match with locality column values.

Comment: What code have you got so far? And how do you define "parts of address column values" and "locality column values" how do you propose to split them up? Be clear here: you only have whole strings, if you can't accurately split them up you're wasting your time

Comment: I have two columns I just need address column strings with unmatch the locality column strings values in the SQL command. 
for eg. I  am looking for a new column with Third Floor, Kalayaan Avenue

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide a minimal repro. ##1-4

Please try the following solution.

It is for SQL Server 2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT  IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [Address]  VARCHAR(1024), locality VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT INTO @tbl ([Address], locality) VALUES
('Third Floor, Century City Mall, Kalayaan Avenue, Poblacion, Makati City', 'Century City Mall, Poblacion, Makati City'),
('Little Tokyo, 2277 Chino Roces Avenue, Legaspi Village, Makati City', 'Little Tokyo, Legaspi Village, Makati City');
-- DDL and data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

WITH rs1 AS
(
    SELECT ID, TRIM(token) AS token
    FROM @tbl
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT([Address], @separator)) AS t(token)
), rs2 AS
(
    SELECT ID, TRIM(token) AS token
    FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(locality, @separator)) AS t(token)
)
SELECT rs1.ID, STRING_AGG(rs1.token, @separator) AS delta
FROM rs1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    rs2 ON rs2.ID = rs1.ID AND rs2.token = rs1.token
WHERE rs2.token IS NULL
GROUP BY rs1.ID;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------------------+
| ID |            delta            |
+----+-----------------------------+
|  1 | Third Floor,Kalayaan Avenue |
|  2 | 2277 Chino Roces Avenue     |
+----+-----------------------------+
```